# Override TeamCity environment variable in Maven

Tags: maven, unit-testing, teamcity, maven-surefire-plugin

TeamCity provides several environment variables that are made available in Maven's `pom.xml`. For example, my build agent has a property `env.JDK_18` pointing to a JRE installation on the server. I use this property in my configuration of the *surefire* plugin in Maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvm>${env.JDK_18}/bin/java</jvm>
        <!-- ... -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Unfortunately, the environment variable is not available on my local machine. Is there any Maven option to define the environment variable locally (in my `pom.xml` file) and have TeamCity override it, when unit tests are run on the build server?

Comment: why are you not creating the JDK_18 environment variable locally as well?

Comment: The definition should reside within the Maven configuration, so other developers can check out the project without having to create environment variables locally on their machines.

Comment: jepp. thats a good thing. but to have developers be able to check out stuff and run goals the JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME variables need to be set anyway. It would just be another one. Since that is more of an infrastructure aspect the JDK_18 variable would be better suited to be found in the settings.xml not the pom itself, unless you embed a jdk in the build. I think there a quite a bit of tweaking / playing around with  properties to make it work. Since its an environment variable in TeamCity I would choose the same thing for developer machines. But you can always overwrite maven properties...

Comment: with the -D flag. So locally you set a property (propertyName) and for teamcity start the build with -DpropertyName=%JDK_18%.